# Apache Poi crashes when trying to open an excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

For some valid files saved with MS-Office this line of code:

```
Workbook workbook = tableFileImporter.createNewWorkbook();
```

leads to the following Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:236)
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:166)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:278)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:250)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:229)
        at service.fileimport.TableFileImporter.createNewWorkbook(TableFileImporter.java:31)
        at controller.EmpfehlungenController.importStipendiaten(EmpfehlungenController.java:164)
        at controller.EmpfehlungenController.access$0(EmpfehlungenController.java:132)
        at controller.EmpfehlungenController$1$1.execute(EmpfehlungenController.java:85)
        at view.dialog.dispatchable.ProgressbarDialogDispatcher$1.run(ProgressbarDialogDispatcher.java:59)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

With files I created with Libre I never spotted the problem.
Maybe the issue is somehow related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807167/issues-instantiating-npoifsfilesystem-object-with-file).

**What do you recommend me to do to fix it?**

Comment: What version of Apache POI is this with? And if it isn't the newest one, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: Get the POI source and look what can cause a NPE at NPOIFSFileSystem:236

Comment: I am using: poi-3.13-beta1-20150723.jar

Comment: We did find out that this only happens if the user has opened the file in excel while trying to load it. So I catch the Runtime-Exception and print an error message to the user.

Comment: @Gagravvar furthermore I did observe that if I call workbook.close after opening a workbook of an xls file with a File object the resource is not freed unil the GC will free it at a random time. But if I pass a FileInputStream to the workbook and call workbook.close and fis.close the resource is freeed. In your documentation is written, that workbook.close closes underlying resources. I think 1st your doc should change: only what wb opened should be closed right? And 2ed I do not know why in my case the resource to the file was not freed.